# Upcoming journal editions: read 'em and ask on the Stack (and get prizes)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As the new monthly issues of your favorite journals are published, we want to remind you to ask those burning questions that pop into your head as you read through *novel approaches, methods and cutting edge or controversial findings*. Stack Exchange consists of remarkably bright and talented researchers and our community benefits greatly from more current and relevant questions. **When you flip through your favorite journal and are downright astonished by some findings or perplexed by a method, share that curiosity here.**

Staying up to date in the field betters your own expertise and sharing those quandaries with your peers furthers the discipline as a whole. To encourage good ole fashioned journal reading (*winks at open access*) **users who ask questions about the current issues of whatever journal they like on the Stack are eligible for a drawing to win a year long subscription to a journal** of their choosing (excluding obscure journals only in print in Kazakhstan with a zillion dollar fee). Before Christmas, all posts referencing (denoted with "citation") a current publication will be entered in the drawing and a random winner of all winners will be announced (plus secondary prizes).

*Tag the posts with "citation" and 'journal name/source'

Comment: @JasperLoy http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110963/168422